# How web browsers decide which resource should be requested

Tags: browser

I have a fundamental question and I am searching for that for a long but I still don't know the exact response for that.

I am working with browsers and web applications. I am wondering how and based on what a web browser decide to send a particular request to the web server.

For example when you enter http://www.google.com inside the address bar of your web browser. the Browser will send a bunch of request to the web server for rendering the web page properly.

Now, my question is that how the web browser decide which request it needs to send to the web server.

1. does it related to some tags like 'link' or 'script' inside the body of the responses.
2. does the browser parse the javascript functions to see if it should send a request based on those functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take an example to explain this one.

Consider you want to search for something and you hit http://www.google.com on your browser. These are the events that unfold to fetch you the page that will let you type in your query.

1. First, the networking stack on your machine will try to figure out which actual internet address matches www.google.com. This is called a DNS lookup. Once it receives a response for this lookup in form of an IP address, it can make a connection to the actual server that is serving google.com.
2. The machine makes a socket connection and uses the HTTP protocol to communicate with the server. It queries for the resource at / (which is the root) of the address you are trying to reach. This is called a GET request. The request is normally described like so: GET /
3. Google will respond with an HTML page. normally "index.html", which gets downloaded by the browser.
4. Once the HTML is downloaded, all linked resources, such as images to render the HTML as well as javascript referenced by the HTML page gets downloaded.
5. The downloaded HTML page is parsed and an in-memory tree is created called the "DOM Tree". This tree contains the elements of the HTML page in a hierarchy. Once the DOM is created, you can see the page being rendered on the browser.
6. During this parsing, the browser discovers more resources to be downloaded, such as images, stylesheets, javascript files. The HTML page references these resources via different tags such as `<img>` for images, `<script>` for javascript.
7. All detected resources are downloaded. Browsers download many of these resources in parallel, but apply them (javascript and stylesheets) sequentially in the order they where found on the page.
8. Stylesheets are parsed, and the styles are applied to the DOM of the HTML page. Sometimes, if stylesheets take longer to download, you can see the "raw" HTML page being rendered before the styles are applied. This happens sometimes over a slow connection.
9. Once the HTML page and related javascript files have been downloaded, the browser calls the "onload" callback function of javascript. Most Javascript heavy applications are started at this time.
10. Once onload is called, Javascript takes over and can attach handlers for different elements on the web page. Once the handlers have all been installed, interacting with the webpage could call one or more javascript functions that are listening for these events.
11. Javascript can also manipulate the DOM (the elements on the page), which results in UI updates (what the user sees) and therefore can be used to build a complete app on a single page.

Here is some more reading on the process: http://friendlybit.com/css/rendering-a-web-page-step-by-step/

The best way to examine this interaction is to use Developer tools on Chrome/FireFox or IE and view the network activity when you visit a web page.

[image: See list of requests on hitting google.com]

Comment: Agree. Found a good writeup on the web. Will add the link to the answer.